# how to access or get value from geojson response given a key

Tags: javascript, python, json, angular, geojson

in the below geojson response, i want to have access on the following

```
type and segments
```

to achive that i did the following

```
    return data["type"] //does not work i receive an error
    return data["features"][0]["properties"]["segments"] //does not work i receive an error
```

please let me know how to access or get value from geojson response given a key
**geojson**:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"bbox":[29.924118,31.205141,29.924728,31.20539],"type":"Feature","properties":{"segments":[{"distance":64.4,"duration":3.9,"steps":[{"distance":64.4,"duration":3.9,"type":11,"instruction":"Head southwest on شارع جمال عبد الناصر","name":"شارع جمال عبد الناصر","way_points":[0,3]},{"distance":0.0,"duration":0.0,"type":10,"instruction":"Arrive at شارع جمال عبد الناصر, straight ahead","name":"-","way_points":[3,3]}]}],"summary":{"distance":64.4,"duration":3.9},"way_points":[0,3]},"geometry":{"coordinates":[[29.924728,31.20539],[29.924568,31.205325],[29.924493,31.205294],[29.924118,31.205141]],"type":"LineString"}}],"bbox":[29.924118,31.205141,29.924728,31.20539],"metadata":{"attribution":"openrouteservice.org | OpenStreetMap contributors","service":"routing","timestamp":1618549441274,"query":{"coordinates":[[29.924728,31.205391],[29.924118,31.205141]],"profile":"driving-car","format":"json"},"engine":{"version":"6.4.1","build_date":"2021-04-12T07:11:51Z","graph_date":"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"}}}
```

**code**:

```
@app.route("/getRouteFromOriginToDestination/<string:originAndDestinationGPSCoords>", methods=['GET'] )
def getRouteFromOriginToDestination(originAndDestinationGPSCoords):
#api_key = request.args.get('api_key')
# startLat, startLng= request.args.get('start').split(',')
# end1Lat, endLng = request.args.get('end').split(',')
global gpsCoordinates
gpsCoordinates = originAndDestinationGPSCoords
isCohesiveData = checkDataCohesion(gpsCoordinates)
if (isCohesiveData):
    logging.info("data is cohesive")
    data = fetchDataForURL(getBaseURL(gpsCoordinates))
else:
    print("data is not cohesive")
    abort(400, 'Record not found')   

#dist = float(distance)
#dist = dist/1000
return data
```

Comment: "returns an error" isn't helpful. please next time tell us *what* error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the json first:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads('{"type":"FeatureCollection"}')
>>> data['type']
'FeatureCollection'
```

Comment: execuse me i tried the same way for dataAsJSON["features"][0]["geometry"]["coordinates"] and it returns an error would you please help me

Comment: show me what you get for dataAsJSON['features']

Comment: you know, one of the beautiful things about Python is the ability to play with data on the command line. the result of every operation is then available in the special variable `_`.